# Webview does not load original image in google image search

Tags: android, image, webview

I am trying to load google image url in webview.
Everything is working fine. but when I select an image, it shows low quality image only (thumbnail).

If I select an image in chrome and other browsers, original image is loaded soon.

Capture on WebView:
[image: capture on webview]

Capture on browser:
[image: capture on browser]

I think I should do something in code. But, I don't know What I should do.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
    WebSettings set = webView.getSettings();
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    set.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    set.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    ...
}

class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String Url) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Would you please help me for loading sharpen image?

Thanks :D

Comment: Why don't you use Picasso to load images directly to image view?

Comment: I found solution myself..  webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); is required :D

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to you code:
`webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

And anyway, probably, glide would be better to load images. I mean Glide / Picasso, they are so similar, so it's up to you.